# Using defaultValue as value if nothing changed while updating API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a book management system. I have a problem with `editing` a book. When I go to my `form` I convey the data from props using them as default values so if I want to edit the book, the `form` is appearing and the data is already in inputs as `defaultValue`. The problem is, when I change for example only two inputs, it will send to API an object with those two data and empty strings for others, so it doesn't take the `defaultValues` as values to send if they don't change.
As for now I will only send a bit of code where I think might be a problem, if you need more code, tell me, would be grateful if you helped me:

Code (a bit of form):

```
<Form onSubmit={handleOnEdit}>
 <Form.Group controlId="title">
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="text" name="title" defaultValue={props.title} placeholder="Write a title of book" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="author">
                    <Form.Control className="control-input" type="text" name="author" defaultValue={props.author} placeholder="Write the author of book" onChange={handleInputChange} />
                </Form.Group>
    </Form>
```

`handleOnEdit`

```
 const handleOnEdit = (event) => {
        console.log(book)
        event.preventDefault()
        axios.put('http://localhost:5000/api/book/'+props.id,book)
    }
```

`handleInputChange`

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value

        setBook((prev) => ({...prev, [name]: value}));
    }
```

Comment: How do you initialize [book, setBook]?

Comment: `const [book,setBook] = useState({
        title:  '',
        author:  '',
        genre: '',
        release_date: '',
        description: ''



    })`